# Is there a way to have the Windows 8 start screen displayed on both monitors?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, start-screen

I have 2 monitors, when I open the start screen it does only open on 1 monitor. Is there a way to have the start screen displayed on both monitors at the same time (like an extended start screen)?

Comment: Good question. As far as I know, no, but I'm not the authority on windows 8. I'll be checking back here to find out.

Comment: No;  There isn't a way to do this.  You can switch which monitor its displayed on.  But the current iteration does not support this behavior.